# How to display video with alpha channel in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I want to play a transparent video in JavaFX. When I open the video in video editing software like Premiere Pro or Hitfilm I can see the transparent background but when I play it in JavaFX(with Media, MediaPlayer, and MediaView) the background became black. My file format is MP4 maybe this is an unsupported format that doesn't have an alpha channel? So my question is how can I display transparent video in JavaFX (like *.PNG image). Thank you very much. I am sorry about my English this isn't my best language!!

Comment: We need your code, did you try something ?

Comment: I have no idea how to do it because when I put a .avi with alpha channel it says that it is insupported

Answer (score 0):

JavaFX media component is very limited in formats and functions.

You could try **VLCJ** ( https://github.com/caprica/vlcj https://caprica.github.io/vlcj/ ) for your task - in most simple way (and most slow also) you can get your video frame-by-frame and render it like BufferedImage with Alpha channel. 
Or you can start with **direct** rendering hardware accelerated player component that is compatible with JavaFX http://capricasoftware.co.uk/projects/vlcj-3/tutorials/direct-rendering maybe it will fit your needs also

NOTE that **embedded** player is NOT compatible with JavaFX